# can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, beautifulsoup

hi everybody I make in my project a search on google with beautifulsoup and I received this message can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str when I try to search this is
search.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# done
def google(s):
    
   
    USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36'
    headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT}
    r=None
    links = []
    text = []
    r = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + s, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for g in soup.find_all('div', class_='yuRUbf'):
        a = g.find('a')
        t = g.find('h3')
        links.append(a.get('href'))
        text.append(t.text)   
    
        return links, text
```

and this is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from netsurfers.search import google
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def home(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')

def results(request):
      if request.method == "POST":
        result = request.POST.get('search')
        google_link,google_text = google(result)
        google_data = zip(google_link,google_text)
        if result == '':
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request,'results.html',{'google': google_data})
```

and this is urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home,name='home'),
    path('results/',views.results,name='Result')
    
    
]
```

and this is a template home

```
<form method='post' action="{% url 'Result' %}" class="d-flex" role="search">
                {% csrf_token %}
                 <input class="form-control me-2 " type="search" placeholder="ابحث وشارك بحثك مع الاخرين" aria-label="Search" style="width:22rem;">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" value="ابحث" >
              </form>
```

and this is the template results

```
 {% for i,j in google %}
         <a href="{{ i }}" class="btn mt-3 w-100">{{ j }}</a><br>
        {% endfor %}
```

I try to search with google with BeautifulSoup library but I got this message instead
can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Answer (score 1):

your input template should have name property

```
             <input class="form-control me-2 " type="search" placeholder="ابحث وشارك بحثك مع الاخرين" aria-label="Search" style="width:22rem;" name="search">
```

Comment: good it almost make works but there is another mistake The view netsurfers.views.results didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: it's work but with 1 result i dont know why

Comment: print google_data variable in views.py and see what is the result

Comment: i make  print (google_data) in views.py where can i view the result i use visual studio cod and the result dont show in terminal

Comment: where do you run runserver command?in vs code terminal ? print before return you should have data in google_data

Comment: print dont work